# is there any way to show various type of Image formats in GDI?

Tags: c#

is there any way to show various type of Image formats in GDI ?

like jpg , png , tiff , PSD ...

(not default .net formats );

Comment: PSD is a photoshop project file, no?  A standard picturebox and Bitmap object is all that you need to display any of those formats.

Comment: Is there something you're trying to accomplish once you have the image formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()` will tell you what codecs are installed.  Look at the `MimeType` property of each `ImageCodecInfo` in the returned array.